# Is it beneficial for users to be able to change the display location of user and system notifications?

Tags: notification, position, customisation, institutionalizing-ux

Some back story. I'm working on a data science platform, and sometimes when working with Jupyter, RStudio, H20, etc, displaying notifications works for one type of notebook but not the other.

Because each of these products has its own set of controls, and more precisely, its own UX, notifications tend to "get in the way" of some controls depending upon which product they're using.

We currently offer a raw-log view, this however is not sortable, searchable, or digestible without knowing exactly what you're looking for. This raw log has everything from starts, stops, errors, deployment output, and setup output, etc. It's completely unusable.

When I propose a design, someone says "This solves the problem [here], but not [here]." However, our app's notifications blocks controls lack a way to dismiss, lack any metadata, and sometimes fire multiple times, creating a wall of notifications.

Because I can't seem to get alerts and notifications prioritized, I have to make proposals that are somewhat out of scope for whatever project I'm working on. During interviews or feedback sessions, users have mentioned that these notifications get in the way, by blocking controls, hence why I would like to propose that the user have the ability to at least change the location, and possibly the type.

I have proposed that we use a chrome(top-control-bar) notification flyout(with metadata and deep links), however, that is met with some resistance.

I'm wondering if…

1. The ROI on allowing the user to specify the display type/position is beneficial, or would improve the overall UX?
2. What are some ways to get the engineering team to consider notification improvements?

If anyone has specific examples of web apps (non-mobile) that use this pattern or offer this feature, I would love to hear/see them.

Comments, suggestions, opinions are always welcomed.

---

Some posts I've read regarding similar topics.

[Alternative method of displaying notification alert to user with awkward icons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49430/alternative-method-of-displaying-notification-alert-to-user-with-awkward-icons)

[Good examples of notification systems (other than iphone/android)?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8769/good-examples-of-notification-systems-other-than-iphone-android)

[Feedback : notification displaying and removal](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60427/feedback-notification-displaying-and-removal)

[Should users be able to customise everything or should the UX team decide for them?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16600/should-users-be-able-to-customise-everything-or-should-the-ux-team-decide-for-th)

[Placement of flash/growl notifications or messages in web application](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39265/placement-of-flash-growl-notifications-or-messages-in-web-application)

Comment: Given the sensitive nature of the data, could you still provide some screenshots showing the problem? Preferably, using some fake information, but should it be hard for you to do it, they can be blurred out.

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard of the software you're using, apart from chrome, but here is my take on this.

Being able to change the location of user and system notifications is beneficial, as you could have system notifications go to the administrator and user notifications go to the local console.

This is similar to how the the IT system was set up back when I did work experience in high school. 14 years ago though, so there might be some changes that I do not know about.

The same configuration can be used in any setting, from EPOS to Super Computing from VLE to home networking.